# Would a question asking for a collection of dialog quotes be on topic?

Tags: discussion

I've done some research on list type questions and it seems the rules around which are accepted and which are unclear at best so i'm looking for some guidance for a specific question I have in mind.

The question calls for compiling a list of quotes from the latest expansion of World of Warcraft and is further scoped to only those pertaining to a specific subject, I've typed up a first draft to include here for your review.

> ## What are the Old Gods up to?
>
> After killing Xavius in the Emerald Nightmare raid, the group is
>   transported to Moon Glade in the Emerald Dream. In this location is a
>   cave where there is a flower that only Shadow Priests can interact
>   with, when doing so Xal'Atath whispers the player with the following:
>
> > "Almost completely gone, as if it never existed. But the Rift is deep
> >     and vast, somewhere down there it stirs. Something has changed, the
> >     last prison weakens. We must prepare."
>
> Also while questing in Azshara it will again whisper the player with
>   this:
>
> > "The Legion burrows deep here. If they burrow deeper, they may not
> >     like what they find."
>
> Both of these lines appear to be hinting at some new developments with
>   the old gods.
>
> I've heard of other things that Xal'Atath will say and know that other
>   artifacts will whisper the player as well.
>
> Given that, what are all the lines in Legion that directly or indirectly talk
>   about the Old Gods?

Comment: Depending on the scope of dialog that you want, it could be out of our hands. If you want too much, the answer becomes just a dump of information that would be difficult to sort through/only useful to you.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf making an educated guess I don't think there would be more than 10 - 20 quotes that fall under the specific topic i'm looking for.

Comment: Okay, that takes care of my worry with it. I don't see a problem with this, as it's completely gaming related. I'll let a more seasoned veteran answer though.